# Can I get "number of users who have created their first object since -date-" with less than 2 queries and 1 loop?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, django-models

GOAL: Get "number of users who have created their first object since -date-". In this case the object is a Django Model named "Creation.

Is there a more efficient way than what I have below? Possibly using a Q object or raw SQL? I'm using MySQL in this case.

```
'''return all users who have created their first Offer since -date-'''
prev_creators = Creation.objects.filter(created__lte=date).values_list('creator', flat=True).distinct()
recent_creators = Creation.objects.filter(created__gte=date).values_list('creator', flat=True).distinct()
return [b for b in recent_creators if b not in prev_creators]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure off hand how to decrease it to one query but you could add a ".exclude" to the second filter and filter out the creators that were returned by the first query.

```
recent_creators = Creation.objects.filter(created__gte=date).exclude(creator__in=prev_creators).values_list('creator', flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: This seems like a great idea, but I'm getting 0 results from it while I'm getting a few hundred results from my list comprehension in the question. I'm really not sure why.

Comment: @kvnn I'm only firing off the top of my head here but I wonder if you change the exclude to be something like `.exclude(creator__id__in= prev_creators)`

Answer (score 1):

A colleague helped me solve this with a much simpler query:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

return get_user_model().objects.distinct()\
    .filter(creation__created__gte=date)\
    .exclude(creation__created__lt=date)\
```